# Mapping using mapstruct : Error:(22,48) java: The type of parameter "quote" has no property named "quote_type"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, mapstruct

Getting the below error when trying to build the mapper class.

```
Error:(20,48) java: The type of parameter "quote" has no property named "quote_type".
Error:(15,53) java: Unknown property "quote_type" in return type.
Error:(20,48) java: Property "type" has no write accessor.
```

Mapper class is given below

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SourceDestinationMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "quote_type", source= "quoteFromSource.type")
    })
    Quote sourceToDestination(QuoteFromSource quoteFromSource);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "type", source = "quote.quote_type")
    })
    QuoteFromSource destinationToSource(Quote quote);

    Value sourceValueToDestinationValue(ValueFromSource valueFromSource);

    ValueFromSource sourceValueToDestinationValue(Value value);
}
```

The Source class is given below

```java
public class Quote {

    @JsonProperty("quote_type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("quote_value")
    private Value value;
}
```

The Destination class is given below

```java
public class QuoteFromSource {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private ValueFromSource value;
}
```

source class

```java
public class Value {

    @JsonProperty("quote_id")
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("quote_description")
    private String quote;
}
```

destination class

```java
public class ValueFromSource {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("quote")
    private String quote;
}
```

Example JSON to be deserialized:

```
{ 
    "quote_type": "auto",
    "quote_value": {
        "quote_id": 10,
        "quote_description": "This is my first quote"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you also add a sample Json object that you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: {
  "quote_type": "auto",
  "quote_value": {
    "quote_id": 10,
    "quote_description": "This is my first quote"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapper might be backwards.

The class that directly correlates to your JSON structure is `Quote`.

The error makes it appear as if you are attempting to instead deserialize `QuoteFromSource`.

**Additionally**, you need to make sure your classes have standard / default getters and setters because by default, Jackson makes use of those when deserializing unless you configure it to do property injection directly (not default)

Example:

```java
public class Quote {

    private String type;

    private Value value;

    @JsonSetter("quote_type")
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JsonGetter("quote_type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonSetter("quote_value")
    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonGetter("quote_value")
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue. I was using the JsonProperty names instead of the actual variable name. After changing mapper class with variable name it worked.                                             @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "type", source = "quoteFromSource.type")
    })
    QuoteDestination sourceToDestination(QuoteFromSource quoteFromSource);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "type", source= "quoteDestination.type")
    })